# Competing  against existing well ranked Websites

Tags: seo, google, competitors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best ways to increase your site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-your-sites-position-in-google)

What can I do to compete against existing established websites with Google page rank 3?

I will try to add more keyword to my site by populating my website with similar articles (not copies) present on the other websites, but will my page get a good ranking since they have good SEO with lots of good articles and Facebook followers?

How can I get customers?

Answer (score 3):

Create articles that are **original**, with good **quality**, **useful** or **entertaining**. Add good photography, infographics or video and keep your site navigation easy to understand and honest.

Spread the word about this articles using social networks, press releases and useful comments on blogs that address the same audience.

And watch the magic happens... in the next months/years.